# Display multiple lines as one line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, display, generalization

I am working with the OSM Dataset and can´t find a way to display rails in a proper way. In a big scale the rails are displaying fine but as soon the lines begin to overlap in a smaller scale I don´t like the outcome. I already filtered the lines to only have the main tracks. But especially in train stations where more rails are running next to each other I get too many overlapping lines.

[image: rails in small scale]
[image: rails in big scale]

Is there a way to display multiple lines as one line without changing the geometry?

I am using the QGIS version 3.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you have render level field in the attribute table or not. The render level field shows value ranges from 1 and above. The value of 1 means the main railway and from 2 and above it shows other railway lines. If you have Render level field, then you can use `Rule-based` symbology to show the railway of the value of 1 always, and other than the value of 1 to be shown at certain scale as shown below:

- `"RenderLVL" = 1 Min. Scale empty and Max. Scale empty`
- `"RenderLVL" > 1 Min. Scale 1:20000 and 1:1`

  [image]

The output will be like this:

A scale value > 20000 it shows as simplified line based on `"RenderLVL" = 1`

[image]

A scale value <= 20000 it shows other railway line based on `"RenderLVL" > 1`

[image]

If you don't have Render Level in the attribute table, then it is better to create one so that you can control which line to render at which scale.